# How to tell if an ArcGIS Service is secure?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#, rest

I am creating a .NET REST SOE for ArcGIS Server 10, and I will need to determine if a map service (or image) is secure or not.

Is there a property on a MapService that would tell me this in either ArcObjects or REST?

Comment: Can you setup https? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069 IIS - not sure on your setup though.

Comment: depends on what you mean by "secure"...

Comment: secured at the AGS server level on services, with un/pw access and potentially tokens as well.

Answer (score 3):

To check if the service is secured from the GIS Tier, you can use the ArcGIS for Server Admin API.

Query the REST end point is this

```
http://yourserver:6080/arcgis/admin/services/yourservice.MapServer/permissions
```

If the REST end point returned "esriEveryone", it means it is public. Else it will return the permitted Roles or Group who can access this service.

You can access the Admin API from here, you would need to use the primary administrator or any administrator login.

```
http://yourserver:6080/arcgis/admin
```

However, to check if it is secured from the Web-Tier, you can check if protocol is HTTPS or the port being used is 443.

Comment: Great answer, but for 10.1+

Comment: This is for 10.7.1 and I have portal setup with it. The service is secured and can not be seen publicly in the rest directory. But when I use this permissions endpoint it still says everyone. Have you run across this?